# Is there a way to list all the commands a user can execute (KSH)?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, aix

I am currently writing a ksh script where I check for sticky bits to see if a unprivileged user can execute certain commands. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to check it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say sticky bits; that's the 01000 bit.  Are you thinking of the set UID  (04000) and set GID (02000) bits?  It's really quite tricky.  Any executable file in a directory on PATH can be executed without specifying any path (e.g. by typing just `ls`).  But any executable on the system can be executed by specifying an appropriate path to it — subject to access permissions, of course.  Then you run into issues with aliases and functions: do they count?  So, are you sure that you want to run a search across all the file systems on the machine for executables, because any of those could be run?

Comment: Currently I have a script which does `ls -ltra x` and the result would be `-rwxrwx--- 1 user xyz ....x`. My goal is to make sure only root can execute some commands (lssec, chsec, etc). I am providing the script some metadata (-r-xr--r--) and doing a string compare of the bits. Do you think there is a more efficient or better way to do this? Please let me know if you have anymore questions. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and yes, there are tools designed for this sort of thing though I don't know how good any of them really are and like JonathanLeffler said doing this is *very* dependent on what you want to test exactly.

Comment: My end goal is to check what kind of permissions are set on this file correctly. The questions I would ask myself would be: Can root execute this? Can certain groups execute this? Can any user execute this? I am just checking to see if a regular user runs this command what would happen? The current structure of script is using ls option but another option I have considered is actually executing the command and from the stderr see if I got `Execution Permission Denied`. However, I am running the main script which runs about 200 scripts as sudo.

Comment: The issue then becomes how to tell the main script only run certain scripts as sudo. I have tried implementing one of the solution I found on Stackoverflow which said to use sudo -u command but I do not know if that's a good idea. Each script does a different task from checking number of CPU to making sure a filesystem is configured correctly. I am fairly new to ksh and AIX so they are not the best scripts. I am trying to understand as much as possible. Any help is appreciated and thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

find(1) is your friend (if it isn't, install GNU find):

```
find / -type f -executable
```